# How to use a single button to take input from multiple Tkinter entries?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

This program is being written in Tkinter. I am writing a program that will have multiple entry boxes where the user will input certain parameters. I want there to be a single button that saves all the entries from all the entry boxes to be used later by another part of my program. At this moment, the entry boxes and the button are done but the button does not do anything. How could I go about making the button read and save all the entries? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the data in the Entries and store them as variables, inside functions and globalize those variables. After that just call all the functions in a separate function. And then give this function as a command to the button.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

e_1 = tk.Entry(root)
e_1.pack()
e_2 = tk.Entry(root)
e_2.pack()
e_3 = tk.Entry(root)
e_3.pack()

var_1 = 0
var_2 = 0
var_3 = 0


def func_1():
    global var_1
    var_1 = e_1.get()


def func_2():
    global var_2
    var_2 = e_2.get()


def func_3():
    global var_3
    var_3 = e_3.get()


def store_all():
    func_1()
    func_2()
    func_3()
    print(var_1)
    print(var_2)
    print(var_3)


b = tk.Button(root, text="get", width=10, command=store_all)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I have used `print()` inside the function to confirm to you that the values are stored successfully. You can just remove those.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of a program that reads contents of one `Entry` and prints it:
https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#patterns

Below you can find code in python 3:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

e = Entry(master)
e.pack()

e.focus_set()

def callback():
    print(e.get())

b = Button(master, text="get", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Just add more `Entry` widgets and read them all in the `callback` method.